# What is the difference between chai and chai as promised

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

What is the difference between chai and chai as promised in mocha framework while using protractor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chai is a BDD assertion library - providing you with common keywords such as `assert` or `should` etc.

Chai as Promised is an extension of that library specifically made to handle assertions with promises (as opposed to resolving them manually yourself).

https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6):

Chai - Test Assertion Library which allows you to test your code with keywords such as `expect`, `should` etc. But while using Chai you have to take care of promises. For example

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

it('should display correct tile', function() {
  var blah = 'foo';

  var title = browser.getTitle();

  return title.then(function(actualTitle) {
    expect(actualTitle).to.equal(expectedTitle);
  });
});
```

On the other hand if you use chai as promised then you do not need to handle promises explicitly. That could be done with the help of `Chai as promised` library. For example;

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

it('should display correct title', function() {

  var actualTitle = browser.getTitle();

  return expect(actualTitle).to.eventually.equal(expectedTitle);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example.

Answer (score 1):

It helps you test code that uses Promises. These can be tricky to test since they rely on callbacks to be executed and are generally async. This writeup might help you: http://www.sitepoint.com/promises-in-javascript-unit-tests-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So to test an angular js app is it better to use jasmine or Mocha framework with protractor?

Comment: @Emna The Protractor docs recommend Jasmine, though both are supported.

Comment: @Gunderson Yes this what i'm searching  what is recommended, thanks :)